# PHP parse Meta Tags of an aspx page failure

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net, ajax

In my project I have a PHP function that parses an HTML page and retrieves meta tags correctly. When I run my function for an aspx page this fails and doesn't create return data even though the aspx page in question has correctly set the meta tags.

The function is:

```
function getUrlData($url)
{
$result = false;

$contents = getUrlContents($url);

if (isset($contents) && is_string($contents))
{
    $title = null;
    $metaTags = null;

    preg_match('/<title>([^>]*)<\/title>/si', $contents, $match );

    if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) > 0)
    {
        $title = strip_tags($match[1]);
    }

    preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*name="?' . '([^>"]*)"?[\s]*' . 'content="?     ([^>"]*)"?[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);

    if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) == 3)
    {
        $originals = $match[0];
        $names = $match[1];
        $values = $match[2];

        if (count($originals) == count($names) && count($names) == count($values))
        {
            $metaTags = array();

            for ($i=0, $limiti=count($names); $i < $limiti; $i++)
            {
                $metaTags[$names[$i]] = array (
                    'html' => htmlentities($originals[$i]),
                    'value' => $values[$i]
                );
            }
        }
    }

    $result = array (
        'title' => $title,
        'metaTags' => $metaTags
    );
}

return $result;
}

function getUrlContents($url, $maximumRedirections = null, $currentRedirection = 0)
{
$result = false;

$contents = @file_get_contents($url);

// Check if we need to go somewhere else

if (isset($contents) && is_string($contents))
{
    preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*http-equiv="?REFRESH"?' . '[\s]*content="?[0-9]*;[\s]*URL[\s]*=[\s]*([^>"]*)"?' . '[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);

    if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) == 2 && count($match[1]) == 1)
    {
        if (!isset($maximumRedirections) || $currentRedirection < $maximumRedirections)
        {
            return getUrlContents($match[1][0], $maximumRedirections, ++$currentRedirection);
        }

        $result = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $result = $contents;
    }
}

return $contents;
}
```

How is it possible to read meta tags from aspx pages?

Thanks in advance

AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a easier way to do this using [get_meta_tags](http://php.net/get_meta_tags)

e.g.

```
<?php

// Load
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');

// Debug
echo "<pre>";
print_r($tags);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: What dou you mean it doesn't work with aspx page? at the end of the day, server side programming language (aspx, php etc...) still produces html output. Using the function I mentioned works. I did a quick test with this `<pre><?php print_r(get_meta_tags('http://uknea.unep-wcmc.org/Resources/tabid/82/Default.aspx')); ?></pre>` and I got the meta tags as expected http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KqvPZVTe - have you tried the function on your aspx page?

Comment: i try for example with http://www.alcass.com/alcass/default.aspx and it not work..why?

Comment: I tried it on your site/url and it appears not to be working. I get the following error: `Warning: get_meta_tags(http://www.alcass.com/alcass/default.aspx) [<a href='function.get-meta-tags'>function.get-meta-tags</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 in test.php on line 1` - it looks like your IIS is throwing internal server error when ever a GET request is being made to that URL - check your IIS logs and see if it has any problem